# Table partitioning and updates / inserts

Tags: mysql, partitioning, update, insert

I'm planning to partition a product table on a website based on the status of the product: 0 or 1 (disabled or active). But I didn't quite understood if the partitioning will work after inserts / updates, as some disabled products may become active and vice versa, plus new active products will be inserted.

Will all the products go automatically to the designed partition after inserts / updates?

Comment: You won't get any performance benefits over a suitably designed `INDEX`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works. The right partitions are automatically populated when inserting new rows or updating existing records.